# Exporting Three.js model in the same expected format from Blender

Tags: javascript, three.js, blender

I am trying to import my own model into the example given in this repository: https://github.com/furnishup/blueprint3d

To do this, as far as I understand, I need to generate three.js model like the ones here: https://github.com/furnishup/blueprint3d/tree/master/example/models/js

I added three.js blender export addon and downloaded several blender models and exported with it. But unfortunately, when I add this model into the application, I got a black screen with console errors:

[image: Console Error]

I think I am generating wrong format, because the file that I generate with the method described above, looks like the following which looks differently from the models in the link above:

[image: My exported three.js model]

How can I generate the same formatted file for my own models?